# Saving data on android

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I want to know how to make an app for android so that an user will sign in and his/her information will be saved.

I need to know what and where is the best way to save this data.

I want to save it that way that a friend could "find" me.

How to make a database like this?

Somebody else like his friend need to get his name. I mean like this:

- You sign in.
- Program gives you a unique name.
- That name need to save on something.
- A friend want to connect to somebody so he write that name in search tab and he get his info. That needs to be done through wi-fi connection.

Comment: Follow this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

Comment: Edit the post, It is not clear at all.

Comment: You can you use SharedPreferences data storage... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple ways to save and load data in your android app

- **Shared Preferences**
  Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
- **Internal Storage**
  Store private data on the device memory.
- **External Storage**
  Store public data on the shared external storage.
- **SQLite Databases**
  Store structured data in a private database.
- **Network Connection**
  Store data on the web with your own network server.

All have their pro's and con's but for saving user sign-in info. I would go for SQLite Db's or sharedpreferences. (depends if you want to save multiple users on 1 device)

More info can be found at the [android developer page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/index.html) about [Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) or [SQL lite DB](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html)

It seems you are rather new to Android development. The above website is your first go-to website when creating your first app, read the ENTIRE website. **Good luck!**

*It seems you want exact answers and pieces of code for a very big piece of your app, this is not where Stack-overflow is for. **You should at least try it yourself**, read up on some material. and if you are stuck, and have no idea why something isn't working you can come back. Again, try any of above methods of saving and loading data in an Android App.*